# Hibernate SQLQuery.list() is very slow for fetching Large number of Records

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, oracle-sqldeveloper

In our application we are using **Struts 1.3.10** and **Hibernate 4.3.11.Final**.
I'm using a *native sql* to execute and fetch data from Database (*Oracle-10G*) .

My `hibernate-cfg.xml` file has the configuration as,

```
<property name="connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:mydatabase</property>
<property name="connection.username">root</property>
<property name="connection.password">mydatabase</property>      
<property name="connection.autocommit">false</property>
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
```

Below is the code snippet which I'm using for fetching the records.

```
String sqlQuery = "Select Report_Name, Report_ID, Start_date, End_date, CASCADE_ID, CELL_IDENTITY from "
                   +"FROM (MSC Msc RIGHT JOIN "
+"(((PRJ_CELL_SECTOR PrjCellSector INNER JOIN PROJECT Project ON PrjCellSector.WORKFLOW_ID = Project.WORKFLOW_ID) "
+"LEFT JOIN TYPE Type ON Project.TYPE_ID = Type.TYPE_ID) "
+"INNER JOIN ((PROJECT Project INNER JOIN PROJECT_DEF_ALIAS ProjectDefAlias ON Project.PROJECT_DEF_ALIAS_ID = ProjectDefAlias.PROJECT_DEF_ALIAS_ID) "
+"INNER JOIN PROJECT_STATUS ProjectStatus ON Project.PROJECT_STATUS_ID = ProjectStatus.PROJECT_STATUS_ID) "
+"ON Project.PROJECT_ID = Project.PROJECT_ID) ON Msc.MSC_NAME = PrjCellSector.MSC_NAME) "
+"INNER JOIN PSAP Psap ON Project.PSAP_ID = Psap.PSAP_ID "
+"WHERE Msc.NW_TCHNY_ID = 5 "
+"ORDER BY PrjCellSector.PROJECT_ID DESC" ;

List<QueryObjectRow> resultList = null;
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.getTransaction();
SQLQuery sqlQry = hibernateSession.createSQLQuery(sqlQuery);
bindParameterWithSqlQuery(queryObject, sqlQry, queryActionAttri, bindValMap);
String rowClass = QueryObjectUtil.getRowClass(queryObject);
sqlQry.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Class.forName(rowClass)));

resultList = sqlQry.list();

session.flush();
tx.commit();
return resultList;
```

Here `bindParameterWithSqlQuery` is just setting some parameters to the query depending upon conditions, and not taking any unnecessary extra time.

My concern is about the statement `resultList = sqlQry.list();` which is taking extremely long time to execute and return the resultset. The query supposed to bring around a million records from DB, and it's almost taking **25 mins** to execute that particular line and causing the program a halt, which is not acceptable. Amazingly when I'm running the query individually in Oracle-sql-developer, it's taking only 7-8 sec to fetch that many no. records.

I've gone through few discussions in stackoverflow, but if anyone specifically suggest something for my issue, it will be really helpful. How can I improve the performance and execute the statement `sqlQry.list()`  really faster for bulk records?

Comment: Use a profiler to find where your program is spending time, also check if the JVM has enough memory, it might be garbage collecting too often because it's close to the limit

Comment: sory,, edited 'lac' to million records...

Comment: I guess `Oracle-sql-developer` is just fetching the first 500 or so rows behind the scenes. Try running it with plain JDBC and you will probably see the same slowdown. Anyway, fetching that many records requires a lot of memory. Maybe you also have a network bandwidth issue.